# dynamic path for fetching files from start and end date

Tags: date, dynamic, path, date-range, databricks

I want to make a only one path variable to fetch all the data from different directories depending upon entered start and end dates.

```
startDate = 2011/05/01
endDate = 2011/05/04

/myfolder/2011/05/01/*.csv
/myfolder/2011/05/02/*.csv
/myfolder/2011/05/03/*.csv
/myfolder/2011/05/04/*.csv
```

**I can do this by extracting separately from 4 different paths.
But i want 1 dynamic path.**

Comment: Did you try using a regex in the part of path that would match the date criteria you have?

Comment: @MrunalPagnis, thanks for replying yeah I can you regex but in my scenario, startTime and endTime can have a difference of years, months, and days each time so I need it dynamic. Knowing that each month can have different no of days, I think I have create my own function that will return a regex expression. Any other alternative or what you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using joda-time.

```
import org.joda.time.Days
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

def dynamicPath(start: String, end: String): Array[String] = {
  val format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd")
  val startDate = format.parseDateTime(start)
  val endDate = format.parseDateTime(end)

  val numberOfDays = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays()

  val dateRange = (for (d <- 0 to numberOfDays) yield s"/myfolder/${startDate.plusDays(d).toString("yyyy/MM/dd")}/*.csv").toArray

  dateRange
}
```

And you would call it using:

```
val folderPaths = dynamicPath("2011/05/01", "2012/06/04")
```

Comment: Yeah thanks. But this will give multiple paths. if I want to process 5 months then array will contain 5*30*24 = 3,600 paths. I want less regex type paths.